# Can't access any pre-existing virtual hosts on apache when mod_wsgi enabled

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to configure mod_wsgi on Apache in order to deploy a Django application.

My server environment is a modified version of the LAPP stack from http://www.turnkeylinux.org/. ***mod_wsgi*** appears to be installed properly. Any apache configuration file changes for my django app have been commented out, so it seems that the problem does not lie with django.

When I enable mod_wsgi none of my pre-existing virtual hosts on ports 80, 443, 12322 (phpPgAdmin) are visible. Disabling mod_wsgi and re-starting Apache brings everything back to life. Apache Tomcat running on port 8080 is fine whether mod_wsgi enabled or not.

Versions are:
Apache 2.2,
mod_wsgi 3.3,
python 3.2 (although 2.7 is installed as well)

I'm probably missing something obvious in the apache config but any help would be appreciated

Comment: What does the Apache log file tell you?

Comment: Getting lots of instances like "[Tue Dec 23 21:51:51 2014] [notice] child pid 1303 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)" in the error log. Nothing significant in other_vhosts_access.log just entries relating to earlier successful accesses.